# `GoogleAppMeasurement` requires CocoaPods version `>= 1.10.2`, which is not satisfied by your current version, `1.10.1`

Tags: firebase, cocoapods

While installing pods getting error - `GoogleAppMeasurement` requires CocoaPods version `>= 1.10.2`, which is not satisfied by your current version, `1.10.1`...Tried other commands like brew cleanup -d -v,brew link cocoapods, brew install cocoapods  but not solving problem..

Answer (score 19):

You need to update cocoaPods. Your version is currently not supported by what you want to use.Try `sudo gem install cocoapods`

Comment: ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first. from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:546:in `block in try_link0' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tmpdir.rb:93:in `mktmpdir' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:543:in `try_link0' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.fra this kind of error its throwing

Answer (score 4):

For me this solution of @Marijn was not enough. I solved finally updating the ruby version on my MacOS

Check the version of Ruby installed on your Mac

```
ruby -v
```

Install the Ruby Version Manager rvm

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Once this command has finished running you need to restart your terminal for rvm to be recognised.

Install the latest version of Ruby

```
rvm install ruby --latest
```

Install cocoapods

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

then setup and install all dependencies again

```
pod setup
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

1.> `sudo gem install cocoapods`

2.> `xcrun simctl erase all`

Run 1 and 2 commands in same sequence worked for me.