# The version of CocoaPods used to generate the lockfile (1.14.3) is higher than the version of the current executable (1.11.3)

Tags: ios, flutter, macos, mobile, simulator

When I try to run a Flutter app in an ios simulator, It shows this error.

```
[!] The version of CocoaPods used to generate the lockfile (1.14.3) is higher than the version of the current executable (1.11.3).
    Incompatibility issues may arise.
```

What I tried : I deleted the Podfile.lock and tried `pod install` but it gave this error

```
Analyzing dependencies
[!] `GoogleAppMeasurement` requires CocoaPods version `>= 1.12.0`, which is not satisfied by your current version, `1.11.3`.
```

OS : macOS Monterey

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\`GoogleAppMeasurement\` requires CocoaPods version \`>= 1.10.2\`, which is not satisfied by your current version, \`1.10.1\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70665922/googleappmeasurement-requires-cocoapods-version-1-10-2-which-is-not-sati)

Comment: just update your CocoaPods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me

Run this command

```
brew cleanup -d -v
```

Then run below command

```
brew install cocoapods
```